# Таймер обратного отсчета с временем из БД и занесением данных в БД каждый час

Tags: javascript, база-данных

Делаю счетчик обратного отсчета, суть счетчика заключается в том, чтобы отсчитывать ровно 1 час и выполнять определенное действие. Время лежит в БД и берется запросом. Вот код подсчета времени:

```js
<?
$email = $_SESSION['username'];
$vremya = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($db, "select * from time where id = '1'"));
$wait = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($db, "select * from settings where `set` = 'wait'"));
$timech = time(); // время сейчас в сайтстамп
$tmm = $timech - $vremya['time']; // время сейчас - время до срабатывания = прошедшее время
$rtt =  $wait['value'] - $tmm; // время до срабатывания

echo date('i:s',$rtt);

                ?>
```

echo все выводит правильно, помогите прикрутить это время на JS вот код счетчика ни как не могу их свести вместе. Если беру время из базы постоянно пишет что время вышло и счетчик по нулям

```js
< div id = 'mytimer' >
  <
  script src = "/style/jquery.countdown.js"
type = "text/javascript" > < /script> <
  script type = "text/javascript" >

  function countDown(second, endMinute, endHour, endDay, endMonth, endYear) {
    var now = new Date();
    second = (arguments.length == 1) ? second + now.getSeconds() : second;
    endYear = typeof(endYear) != 'undefined' ? endYear : now.getFullYear();
    endMonth = endMonth ? endMonth - 1 : now.getMonth(); //номер месяца начинается с 0   
    endDay = typeof(endDay) != 'undefined' ? endDay : now.getDate();
    endHour = typeof(endHour) != 'undefined' ? endHour : now.getHours();
    endMinute = typeof(endMinute) != 'undefined' ? endMinute : now.getMinutes();
    //добавляем секунду к конечной дате (таймер показывает время уже спустя 1с.) 
    var endDate = new Date(endYear, endMonth, endDay, endHour, endMinute, second + 1);
    var interval = setInterval(function() { //запускаем таймер с интервалом 1 секунду
      var time = endDate.getTime() - now.getTime();
      if (time < 0) { //если конечная дата меньше текущей
        clearInterval(interval);
        alert("Неверная дата!");
      } else {
        var days = Math.floor(time / 864e5);
        var hours = Math.floor(time / 36e5) % 24;
        var minutes = Math.floor(time / 6e4) % 60;
        var seconds = Math.floor(time / 1e3) % 60;
        var digit = '<div style="width:70px;float:left;text-align:center">' +
          '<div style="font-family:Stencil;font-size:65px;">';
        var text = '</div><div>'
        var end = '</div></div><div style="float:left;font-size:45px;">:</div>'
        document.getElementById('mytimer').innerHTML = '<div>осталось до выбора: </div>' +

          digit + minutes + text + 'Минут' + end + digit + seconds + text + 'Секунд';
        if (!seconds && !minutes && !days && !hours) {
          clearInterval(interval);
          alert("Время вышло!");
        }
      }
      now.setSeconds(now.getSeconds() + 1); //увеличиваем текущее время на 1 секунду
    }, 1000);
  }
countDown(3600); //устанавливаем таймер на 3600 секунд
<
/script> <
/div>
```

Может есть какие нибудь другие варианты выполнения этой задачи, основная задача счетчика:
1.отсчитать ровно ча
с.(от любого времени главное, что час отсчитывал)
2. Выполнить запись в БД и отсчитывать опять час. (смысл, каждый час по счетчику заносятся данные в БД) Но чтоб этот счетчик был виден на сайте всем пользователям.

Может есть простое решение без костылей которые я тут понаписал? Подскажите хоть куда копать, толком нагуглить ничего не смог ))

Answer (score 1):

Ваша задача не должна решаться средствами PHP или javascript, тем более если отсчет никак не зависит от действий пользователей. 
Как это решить - зависит от используемой ОС и СУБД на backend.

1. Средствами OS Linux можно решить, используя CRON или подобные утилиты, как это сделать - множество статей в инете, достаточно поискать cron schedule job - например [тут](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job) хор статья.
2. Средствами СУБД, если вы используете PostgreSQL (а если нет - срочно примите меры чтобы использовать:-) - можно задействовать

   2.1. pg_cron

   SELECT cron.schedule('30 3 * * 6', $$UPDATE counter set cnt = cnt + 1 ... '1 hour'$$);

   2.2. PgAgent - он устанавливается отдельно и используется для планирования всевозможных задач, типа резервного копирования или профилактики базы данных, опять же, статей масса, [эта](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/19-Setting-up-PgAgent-and-Doing-Scheduled-Backups.html) подойдёт чтобы вникнуть.

Comment: что- то вообще в дебри попадаю((  Может не правильно описал проблему.  Мне нужен обычный счетчик на сайт чтобы его видели все пользователи. Один на всех . функции счетчика: Отсчитать час. (с этим справляется и вышеуказанный PHP , но что бы люди его видели делаю красиво, с двигающимися секундами) после того как счетчик дошел до 0  нужно записать в базу( 0 или 1)данные. и все по новой в цикле. чтоб счетк не останавливался но считал только 1 час. должно же быть какое то простое решение. Как сделать счетчик общий чтоб просто на сайте крутился и записывал в базу значение переменной Х например?

Comment: вы вероятно сами не понимаете что хотите, иначе сразу всё понятными словами и описали бы... в любом случае, на php это делать нельзя... обратный отсчет секунд можно просто на javascript сделать, не обращаясь к серверу... планирование задания и запись в базу - одним из способов указанных выше

Comment: Возможно вы правы, со счетчиком разобрался отсчитывает ровно час для всех юзеров. Теперь думаю как создать действие в то время когда таймер будет 00:00.     Можно как нибудь передать хотя бы 0 или 1 из JS в php? Просто плохо еще яву понимаю. может какая функция есть типа if ->00:00 x=1;  else x=0; и получить функцию php можно это как то реализовать? а из рнр  уже записать в Бд

Comment: Вы отдаленно понимаете суть происходящего... если у вас 1000000 пользователей - зачем передавать от всех событие? А если не одного - тогда что? Пропустить запись в базу??

Comment: Да так и должно быть. это что типа голосования по времени если большенство согласилось в БД идет 1  если не одного тогда 0 в БД

Comment: Трудно было так сразу и написать? Простейший контроллер напишите, и по ajax его вызовите из js, только нада учитывать что в конце часа на контроллер в момент свалится куча запросов

Comment: можно какой нибудь пример или ссылку как этот контролер выглядит?

Comment: зависит от того используете ли вы какой-либо PHP фреймворк, в простейшем случае например отдельный файл vote.php : 
<?
$email = $_SESSION['username'];
$sql = "update vote set cnt = cnt + 1"
// выполнить sql 
echo "OK";

Пример тут https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp и еще 100500 в инете, если поискать